# Why does Facebook Graph API return error on some photos?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am attempting to access Facebook API data on photos I am tagged in, (uploaded by other users). I am using this URL format:

https://graph.facebook.com/[photo-id]?access_token=[access-token]

The access tokens I am using are definitely valid, having logged in with my account and having granted user_photos permission. Some photos this works fine, and it returns the API data. However for other photos it returns the following error:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100
   }
}
```

I can't work out why some photos return this error. Some of the photos producing this error are public and some aren't. As I understood it, I should be able to access all photos I am tagged in through the API once I have granted the user_photos permission.

Update: The same applies when using the [Graph API Explorer tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer). I use the Get Access Token button to generate an access token with user_photos permissions. I get the same error message, even on photos shared with public, e.g. this photo id 10152429955981023

Update: The same photos also seem to be missing when I query /me/photos.

Comment: So the issue is only with photos uploaded by other users? And is it only for some specific users? If so, those users might have disabled apps altogether (“opting-out of the platform”, as FB calls it) – in which case they, and every piece of content they have published, are _completely_ invisible to any app, no matter what permission were granted and whether something is public or not.

Comment: @CBroe Yes, it does seem to be specific users, so I think that is probably the reason. Its a little annoying that I can view the photos through my browser, but not the Graph API, but I guess that's just the way it is. Thanks. I'd upvote your comment, but I'm new to stackoverflow and I don't have enough reputation yet.